# AWS Lightsail - Can't access phpMyAdmin in Terminal on Mac

Tags: phpmyadmin, permission-denied, bitnami, public-key, amazon-lightsail

I have not been able to gain access to PHPmyAdmin for my new Amazon Lightsail Wordpress server. I am using a Mac with Terminal for SSH access. - I keep getting `Permission denied (publickey)` errors.

I just create a the Lightsail account with Wordpress installation and my DNS is fine, my static IP is assigned, My SFTP access is working fine with Cyberduck, but I cannot access phpMyAdmin using the terminal on Mac.

I have attempted to follow all the instructions [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/phpmyadmin/) to gain PHPMyAdmin access.

I created and downloaded a new Key Pair under the Oregon (us-west-2) server where the Wordpress installation/instance is, which I have stored in a directory on my laptop:

> /Users/username/Documents/Projects/New\ Project\ Title/Website/AWS\ Lightsail/keypair.pem

As outlined on the Bitnami instructions page I attempted to open a terminal connection using the following: ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i /Users/username/Documents/Projects/New\ Project\ Title/Website/AWS\ Lightsail/keypair.pem bitnami@PublicIP

After researching online, I attempted to change permissions on the Key Pair *.pem* file to *chmod 400*, *chmod 700*, *chmod 0400*, *chmod 0700* - I then attempted to *chmod 700* the directory containing the *.pem* file. I continue to get the `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

Nothing has worked for me yet, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. This is not a problem with the permissions of the file, it's a permissions denied error when accessing the instance. This is caused because you are not using a valid key when accessing it. The management panel of Lightsail shows the key pair you used when launching your instance and you can download that key from this [page](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/webapp/account/keys). Then use that key to run the ssh command.